# How to check if no condition was met?

Tags: game-engine, game-maker

```
<Check Object "If there is not an object at (x,y)">
{
<Create Instance "create instance of object at (x,y)">
}

...
```

Using Game Maker events, I created a repeated process like the one above, checking one space and then the other, and filling all the empty ones. The code works fine, but I want to add a message at the end ONLY IF NONE OF THE SPACES ARE EMPTY. I tried using an ELSE at the end, but that only uses the very last if.
Sorry for bad wording, I can elaborate if needed.

Comment: I used actions, not code.

Comment: First: go to http://gamedev.stackexchange.com since this isn't using a programming language. Next, try to show us a screenshot or something of your actions.

Comment: @Almo That's unfair. Game Maker's action system is still a programming language, it using a semi-visual system rather than plain text does not disqualify it from StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is an if-else if-else structure. You can do this by nesting conditions:

```
if () {
    ...
} else {
    if(...) {
       ...
    } else {
        if(...) {
           ...
        } else {
           ...
        }
    }
 }
```

Though your code would be easier to read were it to use GML, rather than the visual language, as in GML you can do this:

```
if () {
    ...
} else if(...) {
    ...
} else if(...) {
    ...
} else {
    ...
}
```